# Given an expression. Show an inequality holds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Consider the function

$$g(x,y) = \frac{1}{60}(67x^2+10xy+7y^2)$$

Suppose that $g(x,y) = 1/10$. Show that $x\le5/12$.

---

So we have

\begin{align}
\frac1{10}&=\frac1{60}(67x^2+10xy+7y^2) \\
6&=67x^2+10xy+7y^2\\
&\ge 67x^2 \\
&\ge \frac{864}{25}x^2
\end{align}

$$\implies x^2\le \frac{25}{144}\iff -\frac5{12}\le x\le \frac5{12}\implies x\le \frac5{12}.$$

Is this proof fine? I feel like there is a problem with the fact that I have removed the $+10xy$ since we don't know it is positive. What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: You cannot remove the $10xy$ unfortunately, because as you are saying , it could very well be negative (like $x=1,y=-1$). You have to find a better way to deal with your problem.

Comment: I'll write an answer below, then we can bring up any questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  7(7 y^2 + 10 yx + 67 x^2) = 49 y^2 + 70 yx + 469 x^2 $$
$$ (7y+5x)^2 = 49 y^2 + 70 yx + 25 x^2 $$
$$  7(7 y^2 + 10 yx + 67 x^2) =   (7y+5x)^2 + 444 x^2 \geq 444 x^2 $$

Comment: Well, here's your answer! Completing the square by multiplying by $7$, and isolating the $x^2$ part. You see why we do that? It's because $(7y+5x)^2$, unlike $10xy$, is always positive, so you can remove it from any inequality, which has been done above.